# Angularjs method factory used in js file

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i would like to call factory method in my basic js file but i don't know how do this ?
Can you help me please ?

For example i have this factory :

```
app.factory('rootService', function($rootScope,mainService){

function Factory() {}

Factory.mainService = new mainService();

Factory.prototype.load_root = function() {

    $.post({
        url: my_url,
        success: function(i__json) {
            alert(i__json)
        }
    });
};

return Factory;
});
```

And i would like to call this method load_root in my basic js file 
It's possible ?

Comment: you should not use $.post in Angular.js apps. You will run into serious problems when you do. Use $http instead: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

do this in your "basic" js file(or any other file for that matter):

```
app.run(function(rootService){
    var instance = new rootService();
    instance.load_root();
})
```

$.post does not trigger dirty checking, so you will run into problems if you don't rewrite it to $http.

Comment: there is no error. I do this : app.run(function(rootService){
    alert('plop');
})

Answer (score 0):

your factory:

```
 app.factory('rootService', function($rootScope, $http, mainService){

    function Factory() {}

    Factory.mainService = new mainService();

    Factory.load_root = function() {

        $http.post('my_url').then(onSuccess, onError);


       function onSuccess(i__json) {
                alert(i__json);
            };

      function onError(){
            alert("can't get data");

          };

    };

    return Factory;
    });
```

now you can inject your rootService into controller like that:

```
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope,rootService){

   //call load_root
  rootService.load_root();
});
```

Comment: yes but i used GCM and GCM callback in Android doesn't work with a factory method. I must used a function in basic js file.